# MassTransit capping message rates at 10

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I have a mass transit consumer service set up to work with RabbitMQ and I can't figure out how to increase the speed of the consumer - it seems to hard cap at 10 messages received per second.

I have tried the steps listed here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/masstransit-discuss/plP4n2sixrY/xfORgTPqcwsJ, with no success - setting the prefetch and the concurrent consumers to 25 does nothing other than increasing the acknowledged messages, but it doesn't increase the rate at which the messages are downloaded.

My config is as follows:

```
ServiceBusFactory.ConfigureDefaultSettings(x =>
    {
        x.SetConcurrentReceiverLimit(25);
        x.SetConcurrentConsumerLimit(25);
    });

_bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(
    sbc =>
        {
            sbc.UseRabbitMq(x => 
                x.ConfigureHost(
                    "rabbitmq://localhost/Dev/consume?prefetch=25",
                    y =>
                        {
                            y.SetUsername(config.Username);
                            y.SetPassword(config.Password);
                        }));
            sbc.UseLog4Net();
            sbc.ReceiveFrom("rabbitmq://localhost/Dev/consume?prefetch=25");
            sbc.Subscribe(x => RegisterConsumers(x, container));
            sbc.UseJsonSerializer();
            sbc.SetConcurrentConsumerLimit(25);
        });
```

I'm setting the concurrent consumer limit in two places as I'm not sure whether I need to set it on the default or in the bus configuration, and the consumers are registered via unity - I have omitted the consumer subscription as all subscribers are receiving.

I'm a little confused as to whether there's anything else I need to set or if I need to change the order in which I'm setting the configs.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should not use SetConcurrentReceiverLimit, that is only for specific use cases with MSMQ and transactional queues.

Comment: @IanCotterill: have you been able to resolve your issue? We have exactly the same problem and this SO thread seems to be the only evidence something like this actually happens. And, like yours, RabbitMQ + MT = a cap of 10 concurrent threads despite setting the limit to something higher. There is no issue when switching to MSMQ.

Answer (score 5):

After spending a romantic evening with the problem and trying out different things suggested by Chris, I've found out that there is **yet another** thing you have to do to make it work like it should.

Specifically, **yes**, you need to set the prefetch on the consumer queue address:

```
sbc.UseRabbitMq(
                f =>
                    f.ConfigureHost(
                        new Uri( "rabbitmq://guest:guest@localhost/masstransit_consumer" ),
                        c =>
                        {
                        } )
                );

int pf = 20; // prefetch

// set consumer prefetch (required!)
sbc.ReceiveFrom( string.Format( "rabbitmq://guest:guest@localhost/masstransit_consumer?prefetch={0}", pf ) );
```

But this is still not enough.

The key is available in the code of the `mtstress` tool Chris mention in his comment below his answer. It turns out the tool calls:

```
int _t, _ct;
ThreadPool.GetMinThreads( out _t, out _ct );
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads( pf, _ct );
```

Adding this to my code resolves the issue. I wonder though why this is not required with MSMQ transport, though...

**Update #1**

After further investigation I've found a possible culprit. It's in the `ServiceBusBuilderImpl`.

There is a method to raise the limit, the `ConfigureThreadPool`.

The problem here is that it calls `CalculateRequiredThreads` which should return the number of required threads. Unfortunately the latter returns a **negative** value on both my client Windows 7 and my Windows Server. Thus, the `ConfigureThreadPool` effectively does nothing as the negative value is then ignored when calling `ThreadPool.SetMin/MaxThreads`.

What about this negative value? It seems the `CalculateRequiredThreads` calls `ThreadPool.GetMinThreads` and `ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads` and uses a formula to came up with the number of required threads:

```
var requiredThreads = consumerThreads + (workerThreads - availableWorkerThreads);
```

The problem here is that on my machines this effectively does:

```
40 (my limit) + 8 (workerThreads) - 1023 (availableThreads)
```

which of course returns

```
-975
```

The conclusion is: the above code from the Mass Transit internals seems to be wrong. When I manually raise the limit in advance, the `ConfigureMinThreads` respects it (as it sets the limit only if it is higher than the read value).

Without setting the limit manually in advance, the limit fails to be set and thus the code does as much threads as the default thread pool limit (which seems to be 8 on my machine).

Apparently someone assumed this formula will yield

```
40 + 8 - 8
```

in a default scenario. Why `GetMinThreads` and `GetAvailableThreads` return such unrelated values is yet to be determined...

**Update #2**

Changing

```
    static int CalculateRequiredThreads( int consumerThreads )
    {
        int workerThreads;
        int completionPortThreads;
        ThreadPool.GetMinThreads( out workerThreads, out completionPortThreads );
        int availableWorkerThreads;
        int availableCompletionPortThreads;
        ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads( out availableWorkerThreads, out availableCompletionPortThreads );
        var requiredThreads = consumerThreads + ( workerThreads - availableWorkerThreads );
        return requiredThreads;
    }
```

to

```
    static int CalculateRequiredThreads( int consumerThreads )
    {
        int workerThreads;
        int completionPortThreads;
        ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads( out workerThreads, out completionPortThreads );
        int availableWorkerThreads;
        int availableCompletionPortThreads;
        ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads( out availableWorkerThreads, out availableCompletionPortThreads );
        var requiredThreads = consumerThreads + ( workerThreads - availableWorkerThreads );
        return requiredThreads;
    }
```

resolves the issue. Both return 1023 here and the output of the formula is a correct number of expected threads.

Comment: It should me mentioned that Chris has fixed this in MT 2.10.2.

Answer (score 0):

What amount of work is being performed by your consumer? If it runs fast enough, it's likely that the .NET runtime need not create additional threads to handle the inbound message rate.

We have many systems in production that use specified counts where we match the consumer limit with the prefetch count, and in all of those cases under load, the unacknowledged message count shown by RabbitMQ is equal to those settings. We typically see nearly the same number of threads processing messages. Initially the .NET runtime is conservative in the allocated threads used, but it quickly ramps up to the full thread count when consumers are simply waiting on a remote operation such as an HTTP request or SQL command.

If there is an area of the consumer that is single threaded, it might be limiting thread scaling based on that bottleneck, so verify that your threading model is properly configured as well.

Comment: we have observed exactly the same issue working with Mass Transit - a cap that limits the consumer to 10 concurrent messages with RabbitMQ. Unfortunately, this is a drawback for us. A temporal solution was to fall back to MSMQ for a moment but this is not an option in a long term due to other consumers that bind directly to RabbitMQ. We also have switched to MT 2.10 to be able to use the newly introduced `SetPrefetchCount` but still with no effect. I could describe our scenario in more details but is there a way to contact you and get a chance for any help (other than SO)?

Comment: If you're capping at 10, you need to up the consumer limit for the bus as well as add the ```?prefetchCount=50``` to your queue URI. The new method is meant to override at runtime, the URL approach has worked for a while now. 50 is just an example, FYI. It should be at least your consumer limit.

Comment: Will try that definitely and let you know. This sounds like our last chance, though.

Comment: If you look at https://gist.github.com/phatboyg/308c91dcdaecd16acfc7 you can see the prefetchCount and concurrent handler count match (20 consumer threads). You can recreate this using https://github.com/phatboyg/MassTransit-Stress with the command line options of ```mtstress.exe -instances:20 -prefetch:20 -threads:20```

Comment: I finally resolved the issue, take a look at my answer. Could you write a short comment on that, please?

Comment: I'll merge this in soon for the next release.