# MassTransit, RabbitMQ - FIFO dequeue support

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, fifo, masstransit

I am attempting to prove that MassTransit delivers messages in the same order (FIFO) that rabbitmq receives them.  So far, I am not having luck.  MT seems to randomly deliver messages out of a queue.  I have tried setting both of these bus configuration options to 1:

SetConcurrentReceiverLimit()
SetConcurrentConsumerLimit()

...seems to make no difference.

How do I ensure FIFO delivery via MassTransit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the ConcurrentConsumerLimit to 1 (receiver limit is 1 by default), and set the prefetch=1 on the URI, it *should* be in order FIFO delivery assuming no consumer exceptions are thrown. Honestly, even with a prefetch > 1 (which is important for performance reasons) it should be in-order.

Also, if you're doing this with some sample code, post the sample code and make sure that your producer and consumer processes are listening to separate queues.

```
x.ReceiveFrom(uri) // uri should be unique per bus instance
```

Comment: In fact, this test proves it: https://gist.github.com/phatboyg/3f72359c017ccef21449

Comment: Thank you Chris.  I will use your sample code and suggested adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

There's also a prefetch you need to set with RabbitMQ. [MassTransit capping message rates at 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23997190/masstransit-capping-message-rates-at-10) shows an example of using prefetch configuration on the queue URI.